# Why does the motion of centre of mass is parabola for this particular condition?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

there was a condition in which two bodies of same mass are projected at some angle say $x$ from above and below the same point at some height $h$. i cannot figure out why the path of centre of mass is a parabola? what would happen if it is like a straight line ie along that platform at $h$ height, how does the motion of two bodies will look like then?

Comment: The particles motion , is like projectile motion which is parabola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if masses move free in earth gravity  near earth they always move in parabolas . and the sum and difference of two parabolas is always a parabola.
if the move on  the same plain or platform in a straight line ce center of mass will also move in a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to any textbook discussing the motion of a system of particles. The center of mass (c.m.) moves as if the total mass of the particles was at the c.m. and acted on by the total external force.

If the mass of each body is M, the total mass is 2M. As the external force here is gravity, the motion of the c.m. is that of a body of mass 2M acted on by gravity so the c.m. moves in a parabola.